# jQuery click intermittant

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a remote control system for a web based sales tool that we use, which worked really well under jQuery 1.5.1 now after a revamp of the system to jquery 1.8.1 its intermittant at best.

the system works with a viewer and a controller, things clicked in the controller are saved to the database and read by the viewer which then actions them using the jquery .click() method

code:

```
function ProcessCommand() {

// Setup strings for return values.
xmlProcessCommand = GetXmlHttpObject();

// Setup strings require for function.
var strNewCommand;
var intSplitLocation;

// Get commands from database (AJAX)
var strCommandRequest = "../drone/processcommand.aspx";
strCommandRequest = strCommandRequest + "?sid=" + Math.random();
xmlProcessCommand.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlProcessCommand.readyState == 4) {

        // Items have arrived back, get item.
        strNewCommand = xmlProcessCommand.responseText; // Instructions received.

        // Check received instructions against stored instructions
        if (strCurrentCommand != strNewCommand) {
            // Place the new instructions into the current instructions for overload protection.
            strCurrentCommand = strNewCommand;

            // Extract code
            intSplitLocation = strNewCommand.indexOf("|");
            strNewCommand = strNewCommand.substring(0, intSplitLocation);

            if (strNewCommand != "") {
                // Click the specified ID
                $('#' + strNewCommand).click(); // Click element
            }
        }
    }
};
xmlProcessCommand.open("GET", strCommandRequest, true);
xmlProcessCommand.send(null);

// Loop function.
setTimeout("ProcessCommand()", 500);
```

}

strNewCommand receives the element to click (based on id) and the time stamp from the database to work out if it is newer and to action it.

Simple things like clicking div's works, but some anchors can't seem  to be clicked, even though the correct element name is recieved and the element is unique in the html. it can control lightbox in its entirety, its just the simple things that are making me pull my hair out.

I've checked using alert (bad practise I know) and using firebug, and it shows the element name coming in, it'd just be nice if it told me why it couldn't click it.

any help would be greatly appreceiated.

Answer (score 0):

Had a flash of inspiration over lunch, tried switching some of the plain old anchor links to be "clicked" via an onclick event and it all sprung back into life..

So there you have it, the .click() method isn't so keen on clicking `<a href....>` but is more than happy with `<a onclick=......>`